Kotlin: how to check in functional style that char difference of two same length strings is exactly one char?
I have drafted a function in Kotlin that works good enough for me.
fun diff(l: String, r: String): Int {
  var diff = 0
  for (i in 0 until l.length) {
    if (l[i] != r[i]) diff++
    if (diff > 1) break
  }
  return diff
}

On caller side I simply check that diff == 1.
However, I want to rewrite my snippet as a one-liner in functional style making the function just one return statement yet can't come up with an idea of how to do this.
I think it might be solved using takeWhile or fold functions or some other way.
Please note the strings are the same length (the same number of characters, only ASCII).
P.S.
If you feel that my snippet is not good please share your suggestions on how to improve it in comments.

I would do something like l.zip(r).count { (l_c, r_c) -> l_c != r_c } but you don't specify what happens if, say the length of r is less than l

@emptyjar, I simply forgot to add to the question that I compare same length strings.
Editing question. Thank you!

Please note count() has to go through all items, even if first two are already different. I would rather implement a very small function similar to any, something like moreThan(Int, (T) -> Boolean). Then I would use it as in the example above.

@broot, please add your idea as an answer in order I could try and accept

@emptyjar, please add your idea as an answer in order I could try and accept.
Please note that I am really trying to avoid looking through the whole string length if finding more than one char difference earlier

Given the strings are the same length, you can chain zip and count to get the number of different characters like so
l.zip(r).count { (l_c, r_c) -> l_c != r_c }


zip is something that I missed before. Thank you!
Is there a way to avoid counting all the differences looking until the end of the strings if some N differences are already found?

I am curious to know if using zip function incurs more performance and memory overhead if compared to my old-for-loop snippet iterating over common index of two lists.

@AlexanderItes It will have to allocate an additional collection of pairs, so N + 1 more allocations. You can use a sequence, but it still requires to allocate pairs and additionally, sequences make impossible to inline lambdas, so usually they're even worse performance-wise. Functional style is generally worse for the performance than the classic loop. Usually, it doesn't really matter, differences are neglectable for most cases. But if the performance is critical for your case, then I suggest going with a good ol' loop.
